# How do I pass in environment variables to Android build in react native context

Tags: android, react-native

My react native code uses environment variables to specify the URL of the API it hits so I can do something like this in the react-native js code:
`const endpoint = process.env['API_URL']`

When running the app on computer it is easy to pass in the environment variable when starting the bundler:
`API_URL='http://myapiurl.com' react-native start`

However when I generate my release apk the API_URL is not getting set.

Where do I configure this in the gradle build (or elsewhere) so that the API_URL is properly set for the generated release apk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Quick way to get it working:

Make sure you are passing in the environment variable to the gradle build command
`API_URL='myapiurl.com' ./gradlew assembleRelease`

## Another more sustainable approach:

I would recommend you to look into this project:

https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config

It allows you to specify a .env file to import variables into your code.

You can even specify different environments by naming the files

```
.env.{environment}
```

For example

```
.env.development
.env.production
```

It also allows you to specify what environment to use when bundling your application.

Here is an example for android:

```
project.ext.envConfigFiles = [
    debug: ".env.development",
    release: ".env.production",
]

apply from: project(':react-native-config').projectDir.getPath() + "/dotenv.gradle"
```

These examples are taken from the readme of the project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This looks like a great library however I already have it working a certain way and I got it working for iPhone by adding the API_URL to the Build settings. I'm trying to figure out how to do that same idea for Android.

Comment: Do you have the babel plugin transform-inline-environment-variables installed and are you running the command: 
API_URL='http://myapiurl.com' ./gradlew assembleRelease

Comment: I have the plugin installed. The missing piece was passing in the API_URL when running the gradle build command. I thought I could do that somewhere in the gradle file somewhere...